# How to convince companies to give me projects to build 3d models for them? (By me I mean the company i work in)

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

How do I convince companies to give me projects where we build 3d models as per their requirements whether it be a house, building, street, etc.

Our prices are high because we have professionals who work on the models and use the best quality materials and great finishing touches so how do I convince companies to buy from us despite having a high price?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about professional advice

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a way off-topic question. 
but for the sake of the community I'll give you mild suggestions.

**Don't ask, advertise.**

This means if you beg to do works they will definitely think your desperate. Make them what you.
Show your portfolio and collect your credits and recommendations from other customers.

**High price isn't necessarily top notch**
Autodesk Maya might be expensive but you can definitely do anything with blender as well. It's all about experience and going through the production line. Do you have your works more than expectations? Are you punctual?  Are you up to date on your production pipeline?, it's questions like this that determine your price. 
Never less, show your worth every penny, Show that your very unique than other alternatives. 

Sites of interest

[ArtStation](https://www.artstation.com)

[Blender Artists](https://www.blenderartists.org)

[An article that helps a bit](https://business.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-promote-your-graphic-design-business-part-one--fsw-212)